# What are the available Dragonvale Race wheel prizes?

Tags: dragonvale

After placing 1st, 2nd, or 3rd in a Dragonvale race, you get to "Spin the wheel" for a prize.  It seems to me that the prizes are random even when I get the same place.  Are the prizes consistent by race, or just random?  Is there a finite list, or do they just vary slightly?

Comment: It says on the wheel. It's different if you get firt, second, or third place. Also, my friend told me this cheat, if you want to know what prize your getting, then you go up six spaces slowly, then spin the wheel and that's what you'll get no matter what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a summary of the awards per each level and their range of rewarding. Of note is that once you reach level 35 (currently at the least) you will have the experience rewards removed from the spinner.

- The gold wheel features rewards including Gems (1-2), Experience, DragonCash, and Treats ranging from the thousands (Treats) to the hundreds of thousands (DragonCash). The highest XP reward I have gotten from the wheel so far is 36,000,000 but 2-4,000,000 is much more common.
- The silver wheel features rewards including Treats, Experience and DragonCash in the tens of thousands range.
- The bronze wheel features rewards including Treats, Experience and DragonCash in the thousands range.

Also note that you can get bonuses but that does not seem to have any sort of reason to it as of yet. (I have gotten food twice in a row and gotten an XP bonus but then done that again and not gotten anything but the food both times).

Comment: Thanks @James.  As a side note, I've noticed that experience rewards are no longer on the wheel once you hit max level.  I don't know that it improves your odds really.  I still get plenty of crappy food prizes. :)

Comment: The available experience reward range seems to be related to your current level.  Also, lower value rewards seem to have a greater % chance of getting a bonus.