# Can the result of the DragonVale race spin be controlled?

Tags: dragonvale

I deliberately ask this as a separate question from my [question about wheel prizes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79811/what-are-the-available-dragonvale-race-wheel-prizes), as I believe they are separate topics.

I have observed that I can slowly turn the wheel before spinning, to see the possible prizes.  However, despite attempts to manipulate this to my advantage, the wheel seems to have an inconsistent momentum when I apply what I believe to be similar acceleration.  Sometimes it seems to just stop decelerating when it is near stopped, and other times it stops abruptly.  So, is it at all possible to influence the outcome of the spin or is it just a visual sham with randomized results even when a consistent acceleration is applied?

Comment: @Fluttershy Yeah, I mean why make us spin a wheel?  How about "here's what you won" since it is already decided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visualization of the wheel is indeed a sham. The pause that is experienced when you spin the wheel is actually the result being returned from the server (The game has some blocking issues with networking traffic, you can also see this when breeding dragons and such).

As far as many many many races have proven, there is no rhyme or reason to where the wheel starts or how fast you spin it as to what result you will be given. This simply seems to be random and the wheel will spin at a high speed, slow down and then continue to spin until the prize comes on the screen. It will then slow down one final time, spin 3 more slots and then stop on your prize. The space that just came on the screen at the time of the final slow down is your prize.

Answer (score 3):

It's always six from the starting point (not where you start spinning from, but where it points when you first look at it).

Comment: It is most definitely not 6 from where it started. I just dismissed that with one spin. But it has consistently landed on a dark space. Kinda frustrating if you ask me.

Comment: Six UP from the starting point -- regardless of the direction you spin the wheel, the ending point is separated by 5 squares from where you started. This may not have been the case when this question was asked/answer accepted, but it is the case now (and could be why there is no longer lag when the wheel is spun)

Comment: @Peter It does seem that the behavior has changed.  I'll do some more checks, and if others can comment with their experience that would be great.  I'll move the check if I can confirm this to be fact.

Answer (score 2):

Im not positive but I don't think you can physically controll what exact reward you get.

However I have found out that the wheel has a pattern of dark, dark, light, dark, dark, light spaces where the rewards are shown. I have spent some time examining this and the reward you get is always on the dark spot before the lighter spot. There are 4 dark spaces directly in front of the lighter spaces. You can slowly spin the wheel like stated earlier and see what 4 possibilities that can be awarded to you.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted originally but I'll see if I can figure anything else out

Comment: +1 as this does appear to be the case.. I have only run 6 races so far but it does always seem to stop before one of the lighter spaces.. Unfortunately it still seems to be a random choice from one of those four possibilities.